# Finding equation of cylinder

Tags: geometry

I do not understand word problems and how to figure this out. Firstly, what specific topic tackles the following question(I cannot find online resources) and how can I solve this.
Thank you!

A unit circle in the xy-plane is replicated along the line r(t) = t < 1,1,1 >. Find the equation of the resulting cylinder in the form p(x, y, z) = 0, where p is a quadratic.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what does "being replicated along a line" means...

Comment: This topic seems to cover multivariable function of cylinders and surface area. From my notes~  For cylinders, Im guessing is created by replicating a planar curve (the replicated curve) along a line (the line of replication). Any paralllel line could be used as the line of replication by shifting the replicated curve.When the replicating line is just the (negative and positive) axes this variable is just left out of the equation.

Comment: I suspect what is meant is that you have a unit circle parallel to the $xy$ plane centred at each point $\langle t,t,t \rangle$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I suspected it could be a unit circle centered at each point $\,(t,t,t)\,$ *but leaning*, meaning: laying on a plane perpendicular to the line $\,(t,t,t)\,$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you are supposed to find a formula for $p(x,y,z)$ that describes a cylinder.

$x$, $y$, $z$ are coordinates of a point. Your formula for $p$ is supposed to calculate to $0$ if this point lies on the cylinder, and something that is not equal to $0$ if the point is NOT on the cylinder.

So, how to solve this:
First you need to understand what the line $r(t)$ means.
I will describe the simpler two dimensional case first:

The line $m(t) = t<1,1>$ includes the points:
$<0,0>$ , $<1,1>$, $<2,2>$, $<3,3>$, ... $<n,n>$.

And all the points in between!

The same line can be imagined in 3d:
$<0,0,0>$, $<1,1,1>$, ... $<n,n,n>$

Now you know that $r(t)$ is.

In your problem, there is a talk about the unit circle. Just imagine a disc that lies at the center of the coordinate system. And now on top of this disc there are stacked multiple discs in the direction of the line $r(t)$.

http://postimg.org/image/j7q62bmv7/

Now you need the formula for p:
To solve this you need to know at which $z$ position you are, to know wheter the $x$ and $y$ coordinate are on the cylinder!

Since the line r(t) is very simple, the formula for p is also quite simple:

$p(x,y,z)= (x-z)^2+(y-z)^2-1$

Ok. Now what did I do here?

The circle formula that describes the circle is:
$c(x,y) = x^2+y^2-1$

If you don't understand why this is the case, check out [this wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) under the section circle.

Now when you look at the formula of c(x,y) you may understand what I did with $p(x,y,z)$.
$p(x,y,z)=c(x-z,y-z,z)$ because the circle is moved by 1 in x direction and 1 in y direction for every step in the z direction!.

Comment: Check the FAQ section for directions on how to use LaTeX to properly write mathematics in this site.

Comment: @Nils: Please check that my edit did not distort your message.

Comment: I just edited it myself on include latex code. But I can't see your edit in the log

Comment: sorry, im very new to math.stackexchange and didn't understand how to review your edit. And now I can't accept it anymore!